# Hide anchor link title tag on mouseover

Tags: css, anchor, title

Trying to hide the content of the title tag from an anchor link on mouse-over for IE7/8. For accessibility purposes, the title tag needs to remain(for screen readers).

```
<a title="Move" class="badge move" id="move"> <span>Move Folder</span></a>

#move title { visibility: hidden; }
```

Comment: CSS can't solve this, you'll have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @David Thomas. Found this working solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
});
```

Comment: Darn, I was just going to post that.. Beat me to it!